# Script to Update Values

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble creating a script that changes the price as the user selects the periodicity.

I need to create 3 period selectors, each one should work individually. Example: Selector One changes the value only of div One. Selector Two changes only the value of Div Two, etc.

I tried to duplicate the script, but it does not work.

Can someone help me?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/LittleDamon/y9755dq7/

```
<div id="one">
   $ 3
   <span class="period">Monthly</span> 
</div>
<form class="plans">
   <select id="plans" onChange="ChangeText('plans');">
      <option value="0">Monthly</option>
      <option value="1">Quarterly</option>
      <option value="2">Semestral</option>
      <option value="3">Yearly</option>
   </select>
</form>
<div id="two">
   $ 6
   <span class="period">Monthly</span> 
</div>
<form class="plans">
   <select id="plans" onChange="ChangeText('plans');">
      <option value="0">Monthly</option>
      <option value="1">Quarterly</option>
      <option value="2">Semestral</option>
      <option value="3">Yearly</option>
   </select>
</form>
<div id="three">
   $ 9
   <span class="period">Monthly</span> 
</div>
<form class="plans">
   <select id="plans" onChange="ChangeText('plans');">
      <option value="0">Monthly</option>
      <option value="1">Quarterly</option>
      <option value="2">Semestral</option>
      <option value="3">Yearly</option>
   </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

Problems with your code.

1. Your array declaration was wrong.
2. You gave same ids to all the select tag.

Fixed the code. Check the snippet.

```js
var one = new Array(
    '$ 3',
    '$ 4',
    '$ 5',
    '$ 6'
);

var two = new Array(
    '$ 6',
    '$ 7',
    '$ 8',
    '$ 9'
);

var three = new Array(
    '$ 9',
    '$ 10',
    '$ 11',
    '$ 12'
);

function ChangeText(elemid) {
    switch (elemid) {
        case "plan1":
            var ind = document.getElementById(elemid).selectedIndex;
            document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = one[ind];
            break;
        case "plan2":
            var ind = document.getElementById(elemid).selectedIndex;
            document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = two[ind];
            break;
        case "plan3":
            var ind = document.getElementById(elemid).selectedIndex;
            document.getElementById("three").innerHTML = three[ind];
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
   $ 3
   <span class="period">Monthly</span> 
</div>
<form class="plans">
   <select id="plan1" onChange="ChangeText('plan1');">
      <option value="0">Monthly</option>
      <option value="1">Quarterly</option>
      <option value="2">Semestral</option>
      <option value="3">Yearly</option>
   </select>
</form>
<div id="two">
   $ 6
   <span class="period">Monthly</span> 
</div>
<form class="plans">
   <select id="plan2" onChange="ChangeText('plan2');">
      <option value="0">Monthly</option>
      <option value="1">Quarterly</option>
      <option value="2">Semestral</option>
      <option value="3">Yearly</option>
   </select>
</form>
<div id="three">
   $ 9
   <span class="period">Monthly</span> 
</div>
<form class="plans">
   <select id="plan3" onChange="ChangeText('plan3');">
      <option value="0">Monthly</option>
      <option value="1">Quarterly</option>
      <option value="2">Semestral</option>
      <option value="3">Yearly</option>
   </select>
</form>
```